# XPath - How to select LI-tag contains the 'World' text

Tags: xpath

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
   World
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
   Guys
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to select a LI tag contains the 'World' text
Pls help me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select that tag, just use

```
//li[contains(.,"World")]
```

To get the cleaned up text of that tag, use

```
//li[contains(.,"World")]/normalize-space()
```

Output should be

```
Hello World
```